# How image px convert to word(docx) pic - ext - cx and cy?

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, openxml, docx

How image px convert to word(docx) pic - ext - cx and cy?
e.g. below image is `400 x 400 px`, how can it converted to word(docx) pic - ext - cx and cy?

word xml demo code

```
<pic:spPr>
    <a:xfrm>
        <a:off x="0" y="0" />
        <a:ext cx="????" cy="?????" />
    </a:xfrm>
    <a:prstGeom prst="rect">
        <a:avLst />
    </a:prstGeom>
</pic:spPr>
```

image
[image]

Comment: I don't know this, but I suggest one could find out by doing it in Word manually, and then checking the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web uses pixels, Office uses points. So depending on what you want:

(yourNumber is 400) x 12700 = 5080000 (for points)

(yourNumber is 400) x 9525 = 3810000 (for pixels)

Comment: really appreciate!